# Nodejs nexpect: Get all output lines

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I have a simple case where I want to use nexpect to list all files in a folder, and add some expect() functionality later.

```
nexpect.spawn("ls -la /etc")
        .run(function (err, output, exit) {
            res.send(output);
        });
```

As a result, I just get one line:

```
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root wheel 11 Oct 2 21:42 /etc -> private/etc
```

My expectation would be to get all of /etc, since output is defined as "output {Array} Array of lines of output examined" (https://github.com/nodejitsu/nexpect).

As a side question: Is nexpect recommendable as of today (since it hasn't been updated in a year)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are on a Mac, and /etc is a symlink. Try adding a `/`:

`nexpect.spawn("ls -la /etc/")
        .run(function (err, output, exit) {
            res.send(output);
        });`